# Pgpool Log error: Primary 0 owns only 0 standbys out of 1

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I have pgpool-II v4.0.2 running on an app server managing two PostgreSQL 11.2 database nodes (0 - primary and 1 - standby). The psql -c 'show pool_nodes' command shows both nodes being up:

```
$ psql -c 'show pool_nodes'
 node_id | hostname | port | status | lb_weight | role | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | last_status_change 
---------+-----------+------+--------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------
 0 | 10.1.1.20 | 5432 | up | 0.500000 | primary | 0 | true | 0 | 2019-02-22 21:37:55
 1 | 10.1.3.20 | 5432 | up | 0.500000 | standby | 0 | false | 0 | 2019-02-22 21:44:49
```

However, I've started seeing this error today written to the log every 10 secs after testing online recovery and fallback processes:

```
$ sudo -u postgres pgpool -n
---
2019-02-22 22:15:47: pid 22204: LOG: Setting up socket for 0.0.0.0:5432
2019-02-22 22:15:47: pid 22204: LOG: Setting up socket for :::5432
2019-02-22 22:15:47: pid 22204: LOG: find_primary_node_repeatedly: waiting for finding a primary node
2019-02-22 22:15:47: pid 22204: LOG: verify_backend_node_status: primary 0 owns only 0 standbys out of 1
2019-02-22 22:15:47: pid 22204: LOG: find_primary_node: primary node is 0
2019-02-22 22:15:47: pid 22204: LOG: find_primary_node: standby node is 1
2019-02-22 22:15:47: pid 22204: LOG: pgpool-II successfully started. version 4.0.2 (torokiboshi)
2019-02-22 22:15:47: pid 22204: LOG: node status[0]: 1
2019-02-22 22:15:47: pid 22204: LOG: node status[1]: 2
2019-02-22 22:15:47: pid 22238: LOG: verify_backend_node_status: primary 0 owns only 0 standbys out of 1
2019-02-22 22:15:57: pid 22238: LOG: verify_backend_node_status: primary 0 owns only 0 standbys out of 1
...
(repeats each 10 seconds)
```

I can't figure out what this means and how to fix it. The PostgreSQL streaming replication appears to work properly. That is when I create and populate a test table on primary, I can see the same happening on standby.

Any idea where I can look? Thank you.

**Update 2/23/19:**

I've narrowed it down a little more. It appears that, though my backend node is running in streaming replication, the following query returns NULL (https://github.com/beocommedia/pgpool-II/blob/4.0.2/src/main/pgpool_main.c#L3265-L3268):

```
2019-02-23 15:32:32: pid 17383: DEBUG: verify_backend_node_status: pg_stat_wal_receiver status for standby 1 is NULL
2019-02-23 15:32:32: pid 17383: LOCATION: pgpool_main.c:3271
```

If I query the same standby node via pgpool, I get the status back:

```
$ psql -x -h 10.1.3.20 -c "SELECT status, conninfo FROM pg_stat_wal_receiver";
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------------------------------------------------------------
status   | streaming
conninfo | user=repl passfile=/var/lib/postgresql/.pgpass dbname=replication 
           host=10.1.1.20 port=5432 fallback_application_name=walreceiver
           sslmode=prefer sslcompression=0 krbsrvname=postgres
           target_session_attrs=any
```

Any idea what I may be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I was finally able to fix this. The problem was in `sr_check_user= 'pgpool'` user not having permissions to query `pg_stat_wal_receiver` view. It became apparent after passing the pgpool username in the SELECT:

```
$ psql -x -h [standby.db.node.ip] -U pgpool -d postgres -c "SELECT status, conninfo FROM pg_stat_wal_receiver";
```

The issue can be fixed with making pgpool user part of "pg_monitor` role:

```
GRANT pg_monitor to pgpool;
```

I've asked the pgpool maintainers to update these docs: http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/example-cluster.html